# react-native-navigation with react-native-sentry ios

Tags: ios, react-native, sentry, react-native-navigation

Currently running `"react-native-navigation": "2.0.0-experimental.304"` with `"react-native-sentry": "^0.8.1"`

In the setup for react-native-navigation it asks the user to modify the `AppDelegate.m` to look more like this [example](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/example/ios/example/AppDelegate.m) which replaces `RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation...` with `[[RCCManager sharedInstance] initBridgeWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation];`

Since I no longer have a reference to `rootView` I cannot pass it to sentry setup method `[RNSentry installWithRootView:rootView];`

How can I access that original `rootView (RCTRootView)` so I can pass it to Sentry?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use installWithBridge.

```
[RNSentry installWithBridge:[[RCCManager sharedInstance] getBridge]];
```

Comment: Note, however, that [this is no longer needed](https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry/blob/320651c23144664fb193c34a484a9fbee492dee9/ios/RNSentry.m#L34), but the public docs don't state that.

Answer (score 3):

In `react-native-navigation v1` you can use the code below instead of `[RNSentry installWithRootView:rootView];`:

```
[RNSentry installWithBridge:[[RCCManager sharedInstance] getBridge]];
```

But in `react-native-navigation v2` the `RCCManager` file is removed and for integrating `react-native-sentry` you can use this code, in `AppDelegate.m` file instead of `[RNSentry installWithRootView:rootView];`.

```
[RNSentry installWithBridge:[ReactNativeNavigation getBridge]];
```